# trying to create a .arff file using python

Tags: python, nlp, arff

I want to create a .arff file that displays 10 most useful words from my python code. The format should be like this.

```
@attribute pattern1 {yes,no}
@attribute pattern2 {yes,no} 
......
.......
@attribute emotion {angry,disgusted,fearful,happy,sad,surprised}

@data
yes, no, no,......, yes, happy
no, no, no,....., no, angry
yes, yes, no,......, yes, sad
```

Each of the lines should contain a list of 10 "true" or "false" values, followed by an emotion.

This is what I have written so far but it is not displaying as required. pls help me out.

```
f = open("emotions.txt", "w")
f.write('''@RELATION Emotions\n
    @ATTRIBUTE word{yes,no}
    @ATTRIBUTE class {angry,sad,happy,surprised,fearful,disgusted}
    @DATA\n''')
for word in varall:
f.write("%s\n" %word)
f.close()
```

Comment: How is `varall` defined in your code?

Comment: can someone help me with this pls?

Answer (score 0):

you should check out [this library](https://code.google.com/p/arff/)
It was designed just for this problem, since handcoding your arff output is not a good idea.

For your attributes you'll do something like this:

```
arff_writer = arff.Writer(fileName, relation='Emotions',  header_names=['pattern1','pattern2', ... 'emotion')
arff_writer.pytypes[arff.nominal] = '{angry,disgusted,fearful,happy,sad,surprised}'
arff_writer.write([arff.nominal('emotion')])
```

And for your data:

```
data = [[1,2,'a'], [3, 4, 'john']]
arff.dump(open(fileName, 'w'), data, relation="whatever", header_names)
```